# Missing top section of Joomla navbar in global configuation

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

This has been a long standing problem in one of my Joomla sites, and I can't stand it any more.  Below is a screen shot of what my screen looks like when I click the global configuration button.  Chrome developer tool console shows me the error:

```
content.js:53 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at main (content.js:53)
    at content.js:9
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that there's an error or conflict caused by your site's template.

To check if this is the cause, change your site's template to Beez3 or Protostar. Then login to the backend again and see if it helped.

Another possibility is a module setting in your administrator (ie backend) template.

To investigate this:

- go to **Extensions > Modules**
- towards the top left of the modules window there's a dropdown which is usually set to **Site**, change this to **Administrator**
- I'm sure you are used to seeing a similar view for your site modules, now you are looking at modules published in the admin template
- Check that the **Admin Menu module** is published

If neither of the above help, you could inspect the admin page with Web Inspector, figure out the CSS adjustments necessary, then modify the admin template's CSS or JS. Let me know if you need more help with this.

Good luck!

== Update ==

> Thanks for your suggestions ... neither changed the way the backend behaved

Some other possibilities in case you haven't already tried them.

- clear your browser and site cache
- confirm all your extensions are up to date
- using Chrome Dev Tools > Network tab > JS, check that jquery-noconflict.js is loading

If still no joy, a shotgun approach would be to make and save a backup of your site, then unpublish all the components, modules, and plugins you've installed.

The error should then disappear and you could republish all your extensions one by one so you can pinpoint the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I've tried both Beez3 and Protostar front end templates and neither changed the way the backend behaved. I also tried the Hathor backend template and the same lack of change.  The Admin Menu module was published, and unpublishing/republishing didn't help.  The error in the console leads me to believe that it's not CSS related.

Comment: >The error in the console leads me to believe that it's not CSS related..... yes. I was hoping a default Joomla template might solve that error, but no luck. Please see my other suggestions above @Ben

Comment: the issue has been duplicated across several computers, using different browsers so I'm 99.99% sure it's an issue on the server end.  Everything is up to date.  I'll try your idea of disabling everything, but in the meantime wanted to ask if you thought it could be an issue with my htaccess file(s).  i don't know why, but I have a nagging feeling it's something like that.  BTW - jquery-noconflict.js IS being loaded

Comment: Just disabled all modules, and plug-ins.  Also disables everything that wasn't protected in Extensions > manage (51 items are locked and I can't unpublish them).  Problem still persists.  In case I haven expressed it, I am VERY grateful for you help.

Comment: Hi @Ben, if you suspect .htaccess, you could rename it and instal a fresh file from https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/htaccess.txt . While it wouldn't solve your JS question, have you inspected the page with  Dev Tools to see if CSS changes might at least bring the nav bar back into view?

Comment: A reminder to clear your browser and site caches after every test, and even test with different browsers. Also, there are some plugins like https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jquery-easy that can sometimes help to eliminate jQuery related errors. Normally I would have said that the tests you've done would have eliminated jQuery errors, but we haven't found the cause yet so there's nothing to loose with an extension like jQuery Easy.

Comment: I'm giving up. Thanks again for trying to help me figure this out but between this error and another major issue I think my site it too far gone to save.

Comment: I wanted to mention that you could also check your site's error logs to see if there were any clues there.I hope you have some luck with this at some point!